# Luks/LVM disk encryption: how to change size

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, lvm, luks

I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1 and enabled LUKS. It automatically created the following set-up:

```
[~]: lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1               259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 475,7G  0 part
 └─nvme0n1p3_crypt    253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt
   ├─mint--vg-root    253:1    0 460,1G  0 lvm   /
   └─mint--vg-swap_1  253:2    0  15,7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

What I want is to:

1. Increase the size of *nvme0n1p2* (/boot) to 0.7GB -> 6GB.
2. Increase the size of _mint--vg-swap_1_ (SWAP) to 15.7GB -> 20GB.

Obviously, the extra space should come from *mint--vg-root*. And obviously, I would like to achieve all this without completely destroying my system ("/boot" or "/" change and everything suddenly stops working; This is the experience do not wish to repeat...).

Is there a simple way to do this or is Arch-way ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS ) the only way? Can this be done with GParted (or similar graphical tools) or will I only screw everything up?

I think GParted would allow me to decrease the size of *mint--vg-root* and increase *mint--vg-swap_1* accordingly. But will it destroy my system? Could someone confirm that it indeed is safe to do?

What about the issue of increasing the */boot* partition? This looks quite a bit more complicated...

Any feedback, tips and caveats you could share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue with Linux Mint 20.3. After installation with full disk encryption on a machine with 32 GiB RAM the disk layout looked like this:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1             259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 475,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgmint-root   253:1    0 474,8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgmint-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

As a rule of thumb (and how it worked on Linux Mint 18.3 actually), I wanted swap size to be equal to the size of RAM. There are several threads and questions about this issue, but I've not seen a solution that would work from the installed system. Though booting from the same USB dongle again to "live" version of Linux Mint is not hard, and [this comment from Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1803964#p1803964) worked just fine with small tweaks.

So boot from the USB dongle to the live version of Linux Mint and run these commands in the terminal.

```
# decrypt LUKS
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 vgmint
$ sudo lvs

# shrink root, expand swap
$ sudo lvresize -L -31G --resizefs vgmint/root
$ sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/vgmint/swap_1

# rebuild swap on the partition and check the result
$ sudo mkswap /dev/vgmint/swap_1
$ sudo lvs
```

After reboot to the installed Linux Mint I had the expected layout.

```
$ lsblk 
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1             259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 475,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgmint-root   253:1    0 443,8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgmint-swap_1 253:2    0    32G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```